# Basic unit conversion problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Calculate the approximate number of board feet (one board foot is defined as a volume of $1 in \times 1 ft \times 1 ft$ of lumber that would be available in a log that has a diameter of $34 cm$ and a length of $3 m$. Assume the log is a right cylinder and that the saw mill must make the log into a rectangular prism before cutting it into boards.

So, the diagonal of the square is the diameter of the circle. The circle has diameter $34 cm$, so the square has side length $34\sin{45}=   17\sqrt{2} cm$

So now I have $3(0.17\sqrt{2})^{2}m^{3}$ of wood now I want to know how much bigger this is then one volume of board foot so I just divide one by the other and this was not correct. Am I missing something? 
Edit computer spit back out $4.6$ how did they get that?

Comment: How did you do the division? What is a board foot in $m^3$?

Comment: I had board foot on the bottom it was $2.36E-3m^{3}$

Comment: The volume is the area of cross-section times $3$.  The area of cross-section is the square of $0.17\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo on my part that should be squared

Answer (score 0):

You have $3\cdot(0.17\sqrt{2})^2 m^3=0.1734m^3$ of wood, since the cross section is a square, so you need to square the side length in the volume.
Note 1 board foot is $\frac{1}{12}ft^3$, $1m \approx 3.28ft$ (found on google, but assume it's an equality), so $1m^3=(3.28)^3ft^3=12\cdot(3.28)^3$ board feet.

Comment: I even used wolframalpha to convert $0.1734m^{3}$  to board feet and got the same result. Mine was meant to be squared also it came out wrong though. Computer system might have had error though.